# CakePHP 4 CMS Authentication Tutorial redirection to login not working (subfolder ignored)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Im trying to implement an authentication according to the offical CMS Tutorial: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html#adding-login

But the Redirection implemented here:

```
public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
{
    $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);
```

does not work as expected.

My Installation is in a subfolder like example.com/project1/ and the correct full url would be example.com/project1/users/login but when trying to reach example.com/project1/ the redirection points to  example.com/users/login.

I also tried changing

```
$authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
```

to

```
$authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => [controller => 'users', 'action' => index],
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
```

but this results in an

> parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

error

How do I have to set the redirection or where can I change the "BASEURL" in CakePHP 4?

Comment: Check **https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089086/1392379**

Comment: @ndm thanks for the link but when I change `'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',` to `'unauthenticatedRedirect' => \Cake\Routing\Router::url('/users/login'),` and leave the line with queryParam untouched I get a to many redirects error until the URI is to long if I remove the line I still get a **to many redirects** error

Comment: Sounds like maybe your login action hasn't been excempted from authentication, resulting in a redirect loop, hard to tell from here, you'll have to do some debugging as to where the redirect is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Issue.

I changed the code [according to @ndm's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089086/1392379) to this:

```
$authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => \Cake\Routing\Router::url('/users/login'),
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
```

leading to an infinite redirect, because I had forgotten to add this function to the UsersController:

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // Configure the login action to not require authentication, preventing
    // the infinite redirect loop issue
    $this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I also had to change

```
'loginUrl' => ('/users/login'),
```

to

```
'loginUrl' => \Cake\Routing\Router::url('users/login'),
```

After this it worked for me