# CakePHP 4 Authentication Redirect after successful login

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I'm implementing Authentication in a new CakePHP 4 app (per the CMS Tutorial)

I have had to change the `getAuthenticationService` method in Application.php to be:

```
'unauthenticatedRedirect' => \Cake\Routing\Router::url('/users/login'),
```

and

```
'loginUrl' => \Cake\Routing\Router::url('/users/login'),
```

following suggestions I've seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029465/cakephp-4-cms-authentication-tutorial-redirection-to-login-not-working-subfolde).

That works, and I get my login template, can log in, and the Auth session data is set correctly.

However, after logging in, I'm redirected NOT back to the referring page, but rather to a URL that includes my base app name *twice*:  `http://localhost/my_app_name/my_app_name/my_controller`

So I'm not sure where to set (or rather re-set) the base url for a correct redirect after a successful log in.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow [the example from the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#redirecting-users-after-login)? Avoid using custom implementations when CakePHP already has solved this for you. You'll thank yourself later.

This should works as it should, as it has been tested in another project. In this example, UsersController has the login page.

*In src\Controller\UsersController.php*

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, remember that your AppController also needs a correct setup init function:

*In src\Controller\AppController.php*

```
    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(): void {
      $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        // The login page (as referred to above)
        'loginAction' => [
          'controller' => 'User',
          'action' => 'login'
        ],
        // If no url is provided
        'loginRedirect' => [
          'controller' => 'SomeController',
          'action' => 'SomeAction'
        ],
         // If unauthorized, return them to page they were just on
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
      ]);
    }
```

Edit: It also seems that CakePHP have changed their auth docs (since apparently AuthComponent is deprecated and will be replaced by the authorization and authentication plugins).

*in your Application.php*

```
// In src/Application.php add the following imports
use Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  First, I'm following [the example from the documentation here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html).

I'm using the new Authentication middleware, not the AuthComponent which as you mentioned is deprecated and should be gone soon.  In my AppComponent.php I load `$this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');`, not the AuthComponent.

So, are we comparing apples and oranges?  Also, I haven't changed anything "under the hood"; my workaround is in the UsersController.php.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issues.

It was discussed as an issue [here](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/issues/331) So I followed that.

In my UsersController.php login method, after

```
   $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'home',
            ]);
```

I added this:

```
if(!is_array($redirect)){
        if (strncmp($redirect, '/myapp', 6) === 0) {
            $redirect = substr($redirect, 6);
        }
}
```

And then the double myapp is removed.

Now login redirects work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html), only that I have changed the **routes.php** file so that the / route goes to the Users controller and the login action.

```
$builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
```